# MSSQL to Postgres Replication and Syncing tools

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Use case:
We use a postgres instance for our application but we need to transfer 100tb of data from a 3rd party db to postgres and maintain any updates to the third-party db. We need a tool that works independently of cloud providers as our application is primarily run in private networks.

Ideal functions:
Monitors transaction logs in MSSQL and copies them over to postgres.

Options that worked:
 - AWS DMS (with additional modification)
 - SpectralCore (fullmigrate/replicator) great tools but need performance improvement and only run on windows.
 - Talend was promising but very complex

We're looking for a tool or company that's solved this problem in the past or an opensource software we can leverage to solve this.

Comment: may I ask which solution you have found?